# Why does the new encryption scheme proposed by authors stop an adversary from guessing the subspace of the secret key?

Tags: pairings, group-theory

In  [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22792-9_21), the authors construct an encryption scheme that is supposed to be resilient to tampering and leaking (as opposed to just leaking).

Specifically this scheme:

[image]

If you look at the update procedure they simply multiply the current secret key $g^s$ and multiply it by $g^{Bu}$

If you tamper with this updated secret key you get a mutated secret key $T(g^{s+Bu})$.  How do we know this new mutated secret key does not depend on the random subspace $B$ (in some arbitrary way) ?